# `Git` - update giving the error [.git/index.lock': File exists.]

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I have my repository in the `git`. in the local copy ( my system ) I have made some changes on one of the files.

and I tried to update that file to `git` repository. for that I am running the following command :

`git commit -a "text file updated"`

But i am getting a error as like this:

```
$ git commit -a
fatal: Unable to create 'D:/Projects/gitProjects/color-palette/.git/index.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

what is the problem here? and how to solve this?
what I do is the correct way to update the file from local to git right?

Comment: Try to move the index.lock file to a location outside the repository and try again

Comment: In the `git` or the local machine. can you explain me what is exactly wrong here to learn?

Comment: My guess that the lock file is corrupted. Deleting it (or moving it for backup and restore purposes as I've suggested) will probably solve the issue

Comment: here is my repo `https://github.com/3gwebtrain/color-palette` - at where that file nested to delete?

Comment: The issue is in your local clone of the repository, not on the server. The lock file exists only in your local drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you simply have a lock file.

You can delete if and once you delete it fetch the remote repository:

```
# delete the lock file
rm -rf .git/index.lock

# update the local repository
git fetch --all --prune
```

Once you do it your local repo is updated with the remote repo.

Commit your changes and then you can pull the changes into your branch

```
# add all the changes
git add . 

git commit -m "Message"

# pull the changes which were added to the remote
git pull origin <branch name>
```

---

#### What if the deletion of the index does not work?

In this case you should try to re-clone your project and once you have it copy the desired changes files onto the second clone and then commit them.